# SQL Insert into statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Accounts UserName, Password VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & "', '" & txtEncryptedPassword & "');"
```

When the code is executed and error is thrown, but there is no visible problem that i can see. Help!

Comment: Do not concat strings to generate sql, use parameters.

Comment: It helps if you include the error you are getting in your question.

Comment: You need to put the column list in paranthesis `... INTO Accounts (UserName, Password) ...`

Comment: @Callum, look at my update1... the test mean add your database name..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word PASSWORD is reserved in MS-Access.
You need to use square brackets around that name (Or change it to something different)

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Accounts (UserName, [Password]) VALUES (......
```

Said that, please use a parameterized query to build sql commands.
A string concatenation like yours is easily attacked by hackers using [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)
Also, if the username or password contains a single quote, the resulting sql text built using string concatenation will be invalid.

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Accounts (UserName, [Password]) VALUES (?, ?)"
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",txtUsername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",txtEncryptedPassword);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks the reserved word was the problem, hackers aren't really an issue it is only for a college project.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot parentheses:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Accounts (UserName, Password) VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & "', '" & txtEncryptedPassword & "');"
```

Comment: OleDbException was unhandled  . Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Answer (score 0):

***your doing `()` this mistake and you should must add:***

***your code:***

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Accounts UserName, Password VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & "', '" & txtEncryptedPassword & "');"
```

***you should must change code following as:***

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Accounts (UserName, Password) VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & "', '" & txtEncryptedPassword & "');"
```

***update1:***

```
"INSERT INTO `test`.`users` ( `username`, `password`) " & _
                  "VALUES ('" & txtUsername.Text & "', '" & txtPassword.Text & "');"
```

***update2:***

```
   "INSERT INTO users ( `username`,`password`)VALUES(@txtUsername.Text,@txtPassword.Text);"
```

---

```
"INSERT INTO users (Username,Password)VALUES(?,?);"
```

***note:test means database name you should change your databasename.***

Comment: The table is Accounts

Comment: What does the 'test'.'users' mean?

Comment: This will make the statement just the same though

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 Dim strSQL As String = "INSERT INTO tblDetail VALUES('" & strPersonCode _
         & "','" & strForename & "','" & strSurname & "','" & strDateOfBirth & "'," & strCurrentlyWith & ",'" & strConditions & "')"
```

Do it like that but change to your names.
Declare the values of text boxes as strings and just use those.